# In directed acyclic graphs, is there a dependency in opposite directions?

Tags: bayesian, graphical-model, graph-theory

Suppose we have this graph:
 (a) ==> (b) ==> (c)

Does this mean that P(a|b)=P(a) because the arrows indicate that b is dependent on a and not the other way?
If not, then why do we use arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, more precisely, the arrow from (a) to (b) indicates that variable a is not conditioned by variable b.

Quoting from **Christopher M. Bishop, Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning**, Section 8.1 :

> Then, for each conditional distribution we add directed links (arrows) to the
>   graph from the nodes corresponding to the variables on which the distribution is
>   conditioned.

The next example in the book is that if we have the following factorization of a density $ p(a, b, c) = p(c|a,b)p(b|a)p(a)$ the associated graph will be:

[image: graph]

Comment: But I can factorize that joint distribution in a different manner and I can still be right about it because P(a,b,c) is the same as P(c,b,a). So, how can the factorizations be all true but the graphs are different?

Comment: The more you will refine your factorization, the more you will reduce the number of arrows in your graph. The graphs are different but they "include" each other. To illustrate this : $p(a,b,c)$ can be represented by the graph with double arrows between all of the 3 nodes. Then for $p(a,b,c)=p(c|a,b)p(a,b)$ is represented by double arrows between (a) et (b) and simple arrows between (a) and (c) and (b) and (c). Then refining again with $p(c|a,b)p(a,b)=p(c|a,b)p(b|a)p(a)$ leads to the graph in my answer, in which the double arrow between (a) and (b) disappeared.